# c++ BWAPI exception access violation

Tags: c++, exception, access-violation

is there anybody using BWAPI who gets access violation error when accessing the Unit objects of the current game?

i am certain that the error is not in my code.. anyway.. is there anything i can do to avoid access violation?

i am getting this error sometimes at line with the comment bellow.. this code bellow execute many times and only sometimes i get the error..

```
int Squad::getSize() {

    int no = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < (int) agents.size(); i++) {

        BaseAgent* agent = agents.at(i);

        if (agent != NULL && agent->isAlive() && agent->getUnit() != NULL && !agent->getUnit()->isBeingConstructed()) // this line
            no++;
    }

    return no;
}
```

this is the code that I use to remove an BaseAgent from the vector.. analyze that and see if i can do it better:

```
void AgentManager::cleanup() {

    //Step 2. Do the cleanup.
    int cnt = 0;
    int oldSize = (int)agents.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)agents.size(); i++) {

        if (!agents.at(i)->isAlive()) {

            delete agents.at(i);

            agents.erase(agents.begin() + i);
            cnt++;
            i--;
        }
    }

    int newSize = (int)agents.size();
}
```

the BaseAgent code is on this [link](http://codepad.org/0BpCpHYJ)

Comment: Why not try checking pointers for NULL?

Comment: i ve already done.. is not a null pointer..

Comment: @AlexanderChertov There is simply no way you can check whether a pointer is "valid".

Comment: Is the pointer of a valid type? mb you need to cast it first?

Comment: Terran imba, just saying

Comment: @Caesar this is what i need.. to verify if the pointer is valid.. how could i do that?

Comment: You are missing a `NULL` check for `agent->getUnit()`.

Comment: @juanchopanza i ve already done that also.. i removed from code because the problem isnt that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would speculate that this line:

```
BaseAgent* agent = agents.at(i);
```

is returning some invalid pointer which is not set to `0`.

Looking at your `cleanup` code, it looks a bit complicated. I would suggest

1. looping over the entire vector, deleting the dead elements and
   setting the pointers to `0`.
2. After the loop, use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) to remove all `NULL` pointers from the vector.

step 1

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < agents.size(); ++i) {
    if (!agents.at(i)->isAlive()) {
       delete agents.at(i);
       agents.at(i) = 0;
}
```

step 2

```
agents.erase(std::remove(agents.begin(), agents.end(), 0), agents.end());
```

Comment: @thiagoh he means that the `agents` array can have elements which are e.g. dangling pointers: you freed the memory, but forgot to remove the pointer from the array. After that you attempt to do something with the pointer and get a crash

Comment: i do think the problem is this, @SingerOfTheFall.. the problem is.. who mantains the code is [BWAPI](http://code.google.com/p/bwapi/) which i dont have access.. =/ 
so what else can i do to avoid it? anything?

Comment: @thiagoh, is `BaseAgent` your class or is it the API class? If it's yours, add it to the question please.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall have you seen the removing BaseAgent's code that i ve put in the bottom of the post a few moments ago?

Comment: @thiagoh, yes I'm thinking of it right now, as well as checking the class' code.

Comment: @thiagoh I looked at it and it is too complicated for me. I suggested a simpler and safer approach.

Comment: @juanchopanza good! i cannot test it right now.. as soon as i can ill do that.. cross my fingers.. =)

Comment: @juanchopanza im getting this error now:
`...algorithm(40) : error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'const int' to 'BaseAgent *'`